# Possible to install ubuntu on a second hard drive while in windows?

Tags: installation, remote-desktop

I have an old computer that has no video card and an old ide hard drive. I could put my primary sata hard drive from my main computer in it all setup and ready to go for remote desktoping. Then get on my laptop and remote desktop the old pc. My question is could I install ubuntu from inside windows without needing to restart and select any options or anything? Or  could I could run ubuntu live and remote desktop it from my laptop? I am trying to resurrect the old computer for a server if I can use some creativity.

Comment: I just found an article that mentions WUBI and researched that. That seems like what I would need, but does it install it inside of windows? My ide hard drive is empty, will I be able to point the install directory to the ide hard drive and will it be able to partition it?

Comment: If you want Ubuntu in a separated partition, do not use Wubi. Actually, Wubi is depreciated and has problems with recent versions of Windows. The safest path is restarting the system, booting with the installation media, partitioning the hard drive and installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Wubi installs Ubuntu "inside" Windows as if it were a program. It does not change the partitions on the hard disk, but instead creates a virtual filesystem that is a large file created on the Windows filesystem. You should (see [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=985536)) be able to keep this large file on a separate hard disk volume besides `C:\`, as long as Windows can see it.

To remove Ubuntu, simply "uninstall" it with "Add or Remove Programs" in Windows.